# Autoware Hatem 1.13.0 Object Avoidance Not working

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to do object avoidance with the autoware.ai.hatem openplanner.1.13.0. So far I have been unsuccessful. I have screen recorded the step https://youtu.be/swxcwPBPXUo

I am not sure what is broken. I have echoed the `lidar_kf_contour_track` topic and also checked the rqt_graph to make sure it has a connection with the `op_motion_predictor`. I am not sure what I am missing.

@hatem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390380/autoware-hatem-1.13.0-object-avoidance-not-working/) by [Muhammad Suleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/73042/muhammad-suleman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-11-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) on 2021-11-08**:
In https://github.com/hatem-darweesh/core_planning/blob/openplanner.1.13/op_simulation_package/launch/op_perception_simulator.launch

Try to change useNavGoalToSetStaticObstacle = false

**Comment by [Muhammad Suleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/73042/muhammad-suleman/) on 2021-11-09**:
@hatem Thank you, it works now. The lane-changing feature is work in progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So changing useNavGoalToSetStaticObstacle = false in op_perception_simulator.lauch fix it ?

If so please mark as answered.

About the lane change, It works if it is part of the global path. "Overtaking" is not implemented.

---

Originally posted by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) with karma: 443 on 2021-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Muhammad Suleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/73042/muhammad-suleman/) on 2021-11-09**:
Just curious how were you able to do this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6aCurRXh78 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeE59SwTq4o
If it works as a part of a global planner? Do you mean lane change works if the object is static (part of global planner)?

**Comment by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) on 2021-11-10**:
If you have more than one parallel lane, and your end Goal require that the global bath to change lane. The lane change will be generated.

For the local planner, if static or dynamic obstacle exists and the planner can't change the lane, it will send replanning signal to the global planner.

In the video you have shared the blue line is the global plan, if you notice, when the ego vehicle can't move to the target lane, it create new global plane (extend the blue line for the current driving lane)

**Comment by [Muhammad Suleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/73042/muhammad-suleman/) on 2021-11-10**:
I was trying to give it Nav goal on a lane further away from the curb. But seems like the trajectory evaluator does not like it. https://youtu.be/kmyMGnmcqxM

**Comment by [Hatem](https://answers.ros.org/users/41954/hatem/) on 2021-11-10**:
Try same test with enable smoothing = false for the op_global_planner !